Why do the electric field vector and displacement vector have opposite directions for a capacitor?
I understand that the electric field vector points from positive to negative because obviously that's the basic principal I've used with many problems so far. But why does the electric field go from negative to positive? If that's for some historical reasons, or what physicists decided, I would just nod and accept too. But my textbook was kind enough to explain the reason why the path goes from negative to positive and I want to understand it so bad. The reasoning it suggests is just one sentence: "We shall always choose a path that follows an electric field line, from the negative plate to the positive plate."
Now this made me question two things. First, "Wait, isn't an electric line from positive to negative? Why do you say negative to positive?" Second, "You say 'we shall always choose this way'. But why is that?"
Is there anyone who can answer these two questions I've be struggling with for the last half an hour? Thank you.

Note: I didn't learn polarization yet and this is the beginning of the circut part of the textbook. I only learned flux, electric field, charge, electric potential, electric potential energy, gauss's law, etc.


Which textbook. which page, etc?

@Farcher I'm sorry. I edited the question :)

The text book is not saying that the electric field goes from negative charge to positive charge rather is says that the electric field direction is from positive charge to negative charge but the path of integration is from negative change $(a)$ to positive charge $(b)$ along an electric field line.

When the integration from $a$ to $b$ is done, ie in the same direction as a field line, and the negative sign included it is found that $\displaystyle -\int_a^b \vec E \cdot d\vec s$ is positive, and so the potential of $b$ is greater than the potential of $a$.
If the integration was from $b$ to $a$ with the result being negative, thus the potential of $a$ is less than the potential of $b$, ie in agreement with the previous result.

Thank you SO much, Farcher!

By the way, why is the potential of b greater than the potential of a?

Because an external force has to do positive work when moving a positive charge from $a$ to $b$.
